# Is there an equivalent of user stylesheets or userscripts for Electron Apps?

Tags: electron

Is there any way to add user stylesheets or userscripts to a 3rd party Electron app installed on my machine? Like how you [used to be able to add userContent.css and userChrome.css files](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/24/firefox-69-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-disabled-by-default/) to the right location in Firefox's directory structure to add user styles.

Comment: There’s often a way to open the DevTools window for most electron apps - for example, ctrl+clicking the tray icon 7 times.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. There is. I guess I could use a proxy to add to the existing nonlocal css/js files.

Comment: ...but I don't know how to tell Electron to accept my proxy certificate...

Comment: Electron will use your system CA store by default unless the application was written to perform its own certificate validation.

Comment: For some reason, it's not accepting it. Maybe I added it to the wrong store. I'll open a separate question for it if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yep, it was the wrong store.